How single-tap equalization can be performed in OFDM for perfect channel estimation?
If I have for example IFFT length of 3 with cyclic prefix length of 2 and 3 channel taps, how can I illustrate the frequency domain equalization in OFDM?
For example as far as I know, it's elementwise multiplication of frequency responses, as there is a circular convolution in time domain for ofdm. Thus, for the above example, if x={x1,x2,x3} and channel impulse response is h={h1,h2}. So, for equalization how can I show the illustration to get back the original transmitted sequence by removing the effect of channel tap coefficients?


If I have for example IFFT length of 3 with cyclic prefix length of 2 and 3 channel taps, how can I illustrate the frequency domain equalization in OFDM?

You can't! Your cyclic prefix is shorter than the channel, such that the property of OFDM that equalization is just point-wise multiplication in the frequency domain breaks down.
If you use a longer CP, things work exactly as you describe: the channel in time domain applies what seems to be a circular convolution to the OFDM symbol, so that after DFT it applies a point-wise multiplication, which you can revert by multiplying point-wise with the individual inverse.
